# Constructor error on Android Custom View implemented as an inner class of the Activity?

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a custom view to an Android layout, but get this error when I run it:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

I thought that meant it was missing a constructor, but it doesn't appear to be. Here are the constructors I have for the class:

```
public ChartView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    public ChartView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public ChartView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }
```

I checked the imports, and it is using android.content.Context and android.util.AttributeSet.  I tried rebuilding the app, and reinstalling on my device, but no dice. The view is implemented as an inner class of the Activity that contains it, but is public. I feel think I missed something really obvious...

Comment: Don't make it an inner class.

Comment: Possibly stupid question, but why not?

Comment: What does init do and where do you define it? Can you post the code for it? It looks like it is calling your constructor `public ChartView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` and fails to find the method `init`

Comment: You need to make it a `public static class` if that's what you want.

Comment: Making the view its own separate class seems to have fixed it. Thanks. I figured it would be something obvious.